# Syncronize data between master and client applications

Tags: database, playframework-1.x

I have a Playframework 1.4 application that stores all the data from all branches and multiple branches that store only data of this branch. These branches can work offline, as there may be no Internet. I need to synchronize the data of the branch to the main server and from the main server to the branch server(for example directories, new users)